# Logic/Propositional Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show ($p\land q$) $\implies u$ is true

My professor told me to assume $p$ true, $q$ false and $u$ true to prove this

I don't understand that though, isn't the only time ($p\land q$) true when both $p,q$ are true?

Comment: Remember, in classical logic, $X \implies Y$ is equivalent to $(\lnot X) \lor Y$.

Comment: so how would i go about proving is p is true so p̸   is false, q false so q̸   true and since its an and/or it is true?

Comment: Your instructions were to *assume* $p=\mathrm{T}, q=\mathrm{F}, u=\mathrm{T}$ and evaluate the statement given that. So: $(\neg \mathrm{T}\lor \neg \mathrm{F})\lor \mathrm{T} = \boxed{?}$

Comment: PS: use \neg for logical negation rather than \not, as the latter is a strikeout used for \not =, \not\gt, \not\leq and the like.  $\not =, \not\gt, \not\leq, \not\sim, \not\equiv, \not\subseteq$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implication statement is true if either the conclusion is true or the premise is false.  It's slightly counter intuitive.  A true implication means: if the premise is true then the conclusion must also be true, but if the premise is false then the truth of the conclusion is not set (it may be true or false).  So either the premise is false or the conclusion is true.

Symbolically: $(X\implies Y) \iff (\neg X \lor Y)$

Thus $[(p\land q) \implies u]$ is equivalent to $[\neg (p \land q) \lor u]$ which is equivalent to $[(\neg p \lor \neg q) \lor u]$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense...so how would i go about proving is p is true so $\not p$ is false, q false $\not q$ true and since its an and/or it is true?

Comment: @user146167 You don't need to prove what you were instructed to assume.  Just evaluate the statement given the assumed values. $\neg (1 \land 0) \lor 1 = \boxed{?}$

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is one line of a truth table for the statement $(p\wedge q)\to u$, in particular the line for the truth assignment you were given, $p$ true, $q$ false, and $u$ true.

More importantly, though, what is going on with this problem is what happens with a conditional statement $p\to q$ when the antecedent $p$ is false -- in this case, the conditional statement as a whole is true ("vacuously," i.e. true but meaningless) regardless of whether the consequent $q$ is true or false.  You need this to be how conditional statements work if you want to be able to say things like "the empty set is a subset of every set."